# Changing json libs to deserialize json array from com.fasterxml.jackson to org.codehaus.jackson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have to parse the following json response for "List Networks":

```
[
  {
    "Name": "bridge",
    "Id": "f2de39df4171b0dc801e8002d1d999b77256983dfc63041c0f34030aa3977566",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "Internal": false,
    "IPAM": {
      "Driver": "default",
      "Config": [
        {
          "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Containers": {
      "39b69226f9d79f5634485fb236a23b2fe4e96a0a94128390a7fbbcc167065867": {
        "EndpointID": "ed2419a97c1d9954d05b46e462e7002ea552f216e9b136b80a7db8d98b442eda",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
      }
    },
    "Options": {
      "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
      "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
      "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
      "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
      "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
      "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "none",
    "Id": "e086a3893b05ab69242d3c44e49483a3bbbd3a26b46baa8f61ab797c1088d794",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "null",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "Internal": false,
    "IPAM": {
      "Driver": "default",
      "Config": []
    },
    "Containers": {},
    "Options": {}
  },
  {
    "Name": "host",
    "Id": "13e871235c677f196c4e1ecebb9dc733b9b2d2ab589e30c539efeda84a24215e",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "host",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "Internal": false,
    "IPAM": {
      "Driver": "default",
      "Config": []
    },
    "Containers": {},
    "Options": {}
  }
]
```

Now, so far I have been using com.fasterxml.jackson to convert it to my desired Network.java pojo class and it was working as intended. 
Here is my old code:

```
public static List<Network> getNetworksFromResponse(String jsonInput, Network obj)
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try
    {
        return mapper.readValue(jsonInput, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Network.class));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

where jsonInput is the above json response as a string. The problem here was that there is no root "Network" key to use a simple List networkList pojo. So I have to pass this entire json response into the method to return a list of networks.

Network.java:

```
public class Network
{
    private String EnableIPv6;
    private String Driver;
    private String Name;
    private String Labels;
    private String Internal;
    private String Id;
    private Options Options;
    private String Scope;
    private IPAM IPAM;

    public String getEnableIPv6()
    {
        return EnableIPv6;
    }

    @JsonProperty("EnableIPv6")
    public void setEnableIPv6(String EnableIPv6)
    {
        this.EnableIPv6 = EnableIPv6;
    }

    public String getDriver()
    {
        return Driver;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Driver")
    public void setDriver(String Driver)
    {
        this.Driver = Driver;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public void setName(String Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public String getInternal()
    {
        return Internal;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Internal")
    public void setInternal(String Internal)
    {
        this.Internal = Internal;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return Id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Id")
    public void setId(String Id)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public Options getOptions()
    {
        return Options;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Options")
    public void setOptions(Options Options)
    {
        this.Options = Options;
    }

    public IPAM getIPAM()
    {
        return IPAM;
    }

    @JsonProperty("IPAM")
    public void setIPAM(IPAM IPAM)
    {
        this.IPAM = IPAM;
    }

    public String getScope()
    {
        return Scope;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Scope")
    public void setScope(String Scope)
    {
        this.Scope = Scope;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [EnableIPv6 = " + EnableIPv6 + ", Driver = " + Driver + ", Name = " + Name + ", Labels = " + Labels
                + ", Internal = " + Internal + ", Id = " + Id + ", Options = " + Options + ", IPAM = " + IPAM + ", Scope = "
                + Scope + "]";
    }
}
```

Now there are some other methods which are using org.codehaus library and there is a jar conflict coming. So I have to change my com.fasterxml.jackson to com.codehaus.jackson.
I tried changing the import lines to codehaus libs, and it gives me this error:

```
The method getTypeFactory() is undefined for the type ObjectMapper
```

What is the equivalent method for this mapper.readValue(...) or getTypeFactory() method in codehaus? 
or what is the equivalent method for `mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Network.class)`
in org.codehaus.jackson?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for "going from `com.fasterxml.` Jackson to `org.codehaus.` Jackson" is usually "Don't". This because former means Jackson 2.x, maintained version with more functionality; and latter Jackson 1.x which hasn't been significantly update for past 4 years.

Having said that, Jackson 1.x `ObjectMapper` should have various `readValue()` methods, and can access `TypeFactory`. But it may be that you need to access it via config object; something like:

```
mapper.getSerializationConfig().getTypeFactory();
```

(check the spelling; names may vary slightly)

Comment: Yes, you should use the latest one but I have a very huge codebase which use the org.codehaus.jackson jars so it was not actually possible for me to do it on such short notice. But yes, going from com.fasterxml.jackson to org.codehaus.jackson is discouraged.